# What operation web server do when html/php file requested

Tags: php, html, linux, webserver, apache2

I would like to understand what permissions files must have in order to work correctly on a web server
For now I have apache2 web server and enabled site (at localhost)
In web site directory I have a simple aaa.html file with -rw-rw-r-- permissions, but when I request this page I got - "You don't have permission to access /aaa.html on this server." I thought that html file need only read permission to work correctly. Then I set max permission on the file - 777, but I still get the forbidden error.

PS I have /dir1/dir2/aaa.html.

dir1 and dir2 have drwxrwxr-x

Comment: You never need execution permissions for files targeted by request to an http server, _unless_ you use a CGI setup (which is uncommon).

Comment: One possible cause is that you did not actually allow the http server to actually access anything in its host configuration... Or that you have access rules in place that actually deny access.

Comment: Checked your vhost configuration?

Comment: @Yolo web-server (where html file located) directory is /home/username/new_pvp/toplvl and my vhost config is here https://pastebin.com/uhd7CjWR

Comment: @Yolo I solved the problem, the problem was in main config file (root deny)